# Sending backspace key in SendInput c++ function is not always working

Tags: c++, windows, key-bindings

Some keys in my keyboard are not working, so i decided to create program which would run in background and press these keys for me.

Everything is working perfectly, but there is a problem.

I did that if you hold Print Screen key and press a key below my not working key(for example g, because i want to press t), it deletes that below key with backspace key(because i pressed it) and presses not working key.

Problem is, SendInput function don't work in some places with backspace key, for example if i try to type in Counter-Strike with this, it catches that not working key input perfectly, but not backspace key.

What could be the problem?

```
    INPUT in;

    int main() {
        in.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        in.ki.wScan = 0;
        in.ki.time = 0;
        in.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

        sendInput(VK_BACK); // <--- THIS doesn't work on some programs, input just doesn't send
    }

    void sendInput(WORD k) {
        in.ki.wVk = k;
        in.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &in, sizeof(INPUT));
    }
```

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. And for your code, please post a [mcve]

Comment: @PasserBy edited code, but i don't see what you don't understand about question...

Comment: You typically need to send two input events, one for key down, and one for key up.  You should also note that some applications, particularly games, deliberately choose to ignore synthetic input.  And of course in a game the backspace key doesn't necessarily mean "ignore the previous key" anyway.

Comment: ... perhaps you could use a WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook, which will allow you to suppress the unwanted keystroke altogether rather than trying to delete it.